# Rails: Installing it without the folder structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a ruby app (not rails) that uses a method that is made available by the rails gem. However, I don't want the file structure that it provides, I just want the methods. Is there an option to install rails without all the folders and such?

Comment: It's an old app, so a rails 2 method called `require_library_or_gem` (it's being used by one of my gems, so I need it otherwise it breaks)

Comment: If you need only this method, you can reimplement it in your app. You don't want to drag the whole rails family because of this

Comment: [Kernel#require_library_or_gem](http://apidock.com/rails/Kernel/require_library_or_gem)

Comment: Yeh good point. I ended up just installing activesupport and it worked. If you make it an answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one method is not good enough reason to bring the whole rails into your dependencies. You can just reimplement the method in your code (or, rather, copy/paste from here: [Kernel#require_library_or_gem](http://apidock.com/rails/Kernel/require_library_or_gem))

Answer (score 0):

After you install Rails normally via gem or RVM you can use isolated rails compoenents as you wish, just load them using `require`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# sample ruby script that uses activerecord

require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection( etc, etc, etc );

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   etc
   etc
end

User.all.each { |user| something }
```